# Branch.io smart banner how detect open or download app

Tags: branch.io

I'd like to use branch smart banner because it can open app if it was installed. But i've understood how it work. I need install ios sdk in my app and use setIdentity?

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io here: the smart banner actually doesn't require the SDK to be integrated. `setIdentity` is a completely separate method used for tracking individual users, and isn't used at all for the smart banner.

However, integrating the SDK is definitely the easiest way to get things working, because even without it you would still need to set up a Branch account, configure all your link routing rules in the Branch dashboard, and then enable Universal Links in your app (if it's iOS). Since that is 90% of the SDK set up process, you might as well do the whole thing so you can also take advantage of things like install attribution and analytics!